# Apache Netbeans version 11.1 building error with OpenJDK 11

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-11

I have a project created with JDK 8 and NB 8.2, and I want to migrate this project to NB 11.1 with OpenJDK 11.

The environment is: NB 11.1 (fresh installation) on Windows 10 using OpenJDK 11.0.2.

I copied all the sources and libraries (.jars) into a new project NB 11 / OpenJDK 11 and solved the (few) problems from JDK 8 to OpenJDK 11, but when I built the project, I got this error:

```
error : option -Xbootclasspath/P: not allowed with target 11
```

I think this is a problem related to the Java version, so in the project's **Properties** panel, I changed the *Source/Binary Format* from JDK 11 to JDK 8, and everything worked!

But ... how can I solve this properly (with the Sources jdk 11 format)? I remember that in NB 8.2 I did the same with a project from JDK 7 to JDK 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a NetBeans bug. See [NETBEANS-2452 -Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2452). Read the *Comments* tab under *Activity* for that bug report for some possible workarounds.

Also see this Stack Overflow question which is not an exact duplicate of your problem, but is close: [error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 12 (Netbeans 11.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56272364/2985643)