# Netbeans java web application run main method

Tags: java, netbeans

I recently installed netbeans (12.6) on a new computer. In a previous version (8.2) I was always able to have a main method in a class inside the web application, which I was able to run to do Sys.out to the console, specifically for testing.

Now, with the new install when I try to run the main method I get the following error:

-Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Please assist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Netbeans version 11.1 building error with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299145/apache-netbeans-version-11-1-building-error-with-openjdk-11)

Comment: Also see the question [error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 12 (Netbeans 11.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56272364/2985643). The [answer from Ernestas Gruodis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57292637/2985643) is simple and effective.

Comment: [1] If you are still stuck, update your question to explain why those proposed solutions did not solve your problem.  [2] Why do you have a [java-ee-6] tag for this question? Unless it is relevant, please replace that with the version of Java that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions - I have a full-time job and this is just a hobby, so please allow me until the weekend to try the proposed solutions.

Comment: I tried both solutions without success, but re-installing JDK and Netbeans solved the problem.