# error instantiating servlet class during sign in

Tags: web-applications, tomcat9, netbeans-12

I have made a notelog web project using tomcat as server in Netbeans IDE. It was working fine until couple of days ago, even though I hadn't changed anything, it started showing error.
Whenever I run my notelog and then try to sign in through here[sign in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eLxD.png), it shows me this error [error during sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja0HY.png)`HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [com.ronak.signin]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.ronak.signin]
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Root Cause

java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.ronak.signin.(signin.java:1)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.`. I have also tried to clean and build but it shows this error [error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 15][3]` ant -f C:\Java\Notelog -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild -DforceRedeploy=false -Dbrowser.context=C:\Java\Notelog clean dist
init:
undeploy-clean:
Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/Notelog
OK - Undeployed application at context path [/Notelog]
deps-clean:
do-clean:
Deleting directory C:\Java\Notelog\build
check-clean:
clean:
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Java\Notelog\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
Created dir: C:\Java\Notelog\build\web\META-INF
Copying 1 file to C:\Java\Notelog\build\web\META-INF
Copying 15 files to C:\Java\Notelog\build\web
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
Created dir: C:\Java\Notelog\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Java\Notelog\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 8 source files to C:\Java\Notelog\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 15
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
` This is my signin.jsp code [signin.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LkPF.png) and this is my signin servlet [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHClX.png). I have tried many solutions but still am not able to get it to work. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Please add the error messages as text, not images. Since your build failed the errors refer to a previous version of your servlet.

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57292637/2985643) for resolving the _"option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed..."_ issue. That wasn't the accepted answer, but it will fix your error.

Comment: edited the question to include error as text.

Comment: @skomisa, I don't understand, what does "simply set empty value to endorsed.classpath= at project.properties file." mean??

Comment: Locate the text file _project.properties_ within your project, open it in a text editor, add the string **endorsed.classpath=**, save the file and rebuild your project. That _"option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed..."_ issue should be fixed. As an unrelated matter, you should also update your question to display your code as text within the question rather than as images.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. First I thought it was a IDE problem so I changed my IDE and made another project in eclipse. At first the project worked but next day I encountered the same problem, so then I realised that this problem only occured when I tried to sign in.. And the only thing different in the sign servlet was that it used mysql.  So then I deleted my mysql connector and downloaded it again. This solved my problem. So connector jar file must have somehow gotten corrupted. Although thank you to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked Compile on Save in Project Properties and it works.
Netbeans 12.3 / Ant